# Testing Homepage in Django returning 404

Tags: python, django, django-testing

Writing a Django test to test if the home page properly loads. The homepage of my site isn't '/' but rather '/home/' and the '/' and '/home' actually redirects to '/home/'

so I have written the following test suite for this:

**tests_main.py**

```
from django.test import TestCase


class homepage_redirects(TestCase):
    def test_redirect_homepage(self):
        r1 = self.client.get('/')
        r2 = self.client.get('/home')
        self.assertEqual(r1.status_code, 301)
        self.assertEqual(r1.url, '/home/')
        self.assertEqual(r2.status_code, 301)
        self.assertEqual(r2.url, '/home/')


class homepage_loads(TestCase):
    def test_homepage(self):
        r = self.client.get('/home/')
        self.assertEqual(r.status_code, 200)
```

For some reason, `homepage_redirects` tests don't fail, but the `homepage_loads` fails with the following traceback.

**Traceback**

```
self.assertEqual(r.status_code, 200)
AssertionError: 404 != 200
```

Weirdly enough, if I go to the python django shell,  I should be getting a 200 status code.

**Python Shell**

```
In[1]: from django.test import Client

In[2]: c = Client()

In[3]: c.get('/home/')
Out[3]: <HttpResponse status_code=200, "text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

What am I doing wrong?

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render


def home_page(request):
    return render(request, 'app/home_page.html')
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('home/', views.home_page),
]
```

Comment: Can you show us the view function and url config for that view?

Comment: @solarismoke added view function and url config

Answer (score 0):

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('home/', views.home_page),
]
```

you might want to add ? in your URLs. such as

```
urlpatterns = [
    path(r'^admin/?', admin.site.urls),
    path(r'^home/?', views.home_page),
]
```